# Creating an edit detail view sheet that needs confirmation in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

On Xcode 13 Beta 3, I am trying to find a good solution for an edit detail view presented in a sheet that needs to explicitly be confirmed.

In the `DetailEditView`, I initialise a `@State` property (`editingModel`) which is initialised from a `@Binding` (`model`) that I hand down.

```swift
struct DetailEditView: View {
    @Binding var model: Model
    @Binding var isEditing: Bool
    
    @State private var editingModel: Model
    
    init(model: Binding<Model>, isEditing: Binding<Bool>) {
        self._model = model
        self._isEditing = isEditing
        self._editingModel = State(initialValue: model.wrappedValue)
    }
//...
```

When I tap/press the confirm button in my sheet, I want to assign the altered `editingModel` to the passed `model`.

```swift
 Button {
                    #warning("My expectation (saving changes by assigning `editingModel` to `model`) fails here…")
                    model = editingModel
                    isEditing = false
                } label: {
                    Text("Done")
                }
//...
```

While I do not have any build errors, the code does not work as expected–and I don't understand why. Look out for my `#warning`: that's where my code does not work as expected.

For all I know this could be a bug in the Xcode 13 Beta–or am I misunderstanding something fundamentally?

Here's all the code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

//MARK: - Main
@main
struct so_multipleSheetsApp: App {
    @StateObject private var modelStore = ModelStore()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(modelStore)
        }
    }
}

//MARK: - Views
struct ContentView: View {
    @SceneStorage("selection") var selection: Model.ID?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            SidebarView(selection: $selection)
            DetailView(modelSelection: $selection)
        }
    }
}

struct SidebarView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject  var modelStore: ModelStore
    @Binding var selection: Model.ID?
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach($modelStore.models) { $modelItem in
                NavigationLink {
                    DetailView(modelSelection: $selection)
                } label: {
                    Text(modelItem.id)
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject  var modelStore: ModelStore
    @Binding var modelSelection: Model.ID?
    
    @State private var isEditing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text(modelBinding.wrappedValue.id)
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isEditing) {
            DetailEditView(model: modelBinding, isEditing: $isEditing)
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem {
                Button {
                    isEditing = true
                } label: {
                    Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil")
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    var modelBinding: Binding<Model> {
        $modelStore[modelSelection]
    }
}

struct DetailEditView: View {
    @Binding var model: Model
    @Binding var isEditing: Bool
    
    @State private var editingModel: Model
    
    init(model: Binding<Model>, isEditing: Binding<Bool>) {
        self._model = model
        self._isEditing = isEditing
        self._editingModel = State(initialValue: model.wrappedValue)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                TextField("Model Id", text: $editingModel.id)
            }
            Spacer()
            Divider()
            HStack {
                Button {
                    isEditing = false
                } label: {
                    Text("Cancel")
                }
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    #warning("My expectation (saving changes by assigning `editingModel` to `model`) fails here…")
                    model = editingModel
                    isEditing = false
                } label: {
                    Text("Done")
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        
    }
}


//MARK: - Store
class ModelStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var models: [Model] = Model.mockModelArray()
    
    subscript(modelId: Model.ID?) -> Model {
        get {
            if let id = modelId {
                if let modelIndex = models.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id }) {
                    return models[modelIndex]
                }
            }
            
            if models.isEmpty {
                return Model(id: UUID().uuidString)
            } else {
                return models[0]
            }
        }
        
        set(newValue) {
            if let id = modelId {
                if let modelIndex = models.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id }) {
                    models[modelIndex] = newValue
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//MARK: - Models
struct Model: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    
    static func mockModel() -> Model {
        Model(id: UUID().uuidString)
    }
    
    static func mockModelArray() -> [Model] {
        var array = [Model]()
        for _ in 0..<5 {
            array.append(mockModel())
        }
        return array
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your expectation? What do you want to happen upon  confirmation?

Comment: I want to assign my `editingModel` to `model`, the latter being a computed property of `DetailView`: `var modelBinding: Binding<Model> { $modelStore[modelSelection] }` (please also note my custom subscripting in `ModalStore` to enable the above creation of the binding)

Comment: Did my anwer help you? If not, let me know.

Comment: I will require some more time to look into it. My biggest and most obvious mistake-altering the I’d-is fixed already. Thanks for your input so far, will investigate when I’m back at my Mac.

Answer (score 2):

At first, do not edit id of Model. Instead use a new property and edit it.

```
//MARK: - Models
struct Model: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var content: String
    static func mockModel() -> Model {
        Model(content: UUID().uuidString)
    }
    
    static func mockModelArray() -> [Model] {
        var array = [Model]()
        for _ in 0..<5 {
            array.append(mockModel())
        }
        return array
    }
}
```

---

For the first time you are in `DetailView`, selected model is not among the `$modelStore.models`. You need to send the first object of `` to the `DetailsView`.

```
@main
struct so_multipleSheetsApp: App {
    @StateObject private var modelStore = ModelStore()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(selection: $modelStore.models.first!)
                .environmentObject(modelStore)
        }
    }
}
```

When you choose a model from `SidebarView`, the model in `DetailView` does not get updated. Send $`modelItem` to `DetailView` instead.

```
struct SidebarView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject  var modelStore: ModelStore
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach($modelStore.models) { $modelItem in
                NavigationLink {
                    DetailView(modelSelection: $modelItem)
                } label: {
                    Text(modelItem.content)
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In `DetailView`, remove `modelBinding` and send `modelSelection` to `DetailEditView`.

```
struct DetailEditView: View {
    @Binding var model: Model
    @Binding var isEditing: Bool
    
    @State private var editingModel: Model
    
    init(model: Binding<Model>, isEditing: Binding<Bool>) {
        self._model = model
        self._isEditing = isEditing
        self._editingModel = State(initialValue: model.wrappedValue)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                TextField("Model Id", text: $editingModel.content)
            }
            Spacer()
            Divider()
            HStack {
                Button {
                    isEditing = false
                } label: {
                    Text("Cancel")
                }
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    model = editingModel
                    isEditing = false
                } label: {
                    Text("Done")
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        
    }
}
```

#### All the code

```
@main
struct so_multipleSheetsApp: App {
    @StateObject private var modelStore = ModelStore()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(selection: $modelStore.models.first!)
                .environmentObject(modelStore)
        }
    }
}


//MARK: - Views
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var selection: Model

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            SidebarView()
            DetailView(modelSelection: $selection)
        }
    }
}

struct SidebarView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject  var modelStore: ModelStore
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach($modelStore.models) { $modelItem in
                NavigationLink {
                    DetailView(modelSelection: $modelItem)
                } label: {
                    Text(modelItem.content)
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject  var modelStore: ModelStore
    @Binding var modelSelection: Model
    
    @State private var isEditing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text(modelSelection.content)
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isEditing) {
            DetailEditView(model: $modelSelection, isEditing: $isEditing)
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem {
                Button {
                    isEditing = true
                } label: {
                    Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil")
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailEditView: View {
    @Binding var model: Model
    @Binding var isEditing: Bool
    
    @State private var editingModel: Model
    
    init(model: Binding<Model>, isEditing: Binding<Bool>) {
        self._model = model
        self._isEditing = isEditing
        self._editingModel = State(initialValue: model.wrappedValue)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                TextField("Model Id", text: $editingModel.content)
            }
            Spacer()
            Divider()
            HStack {
                Button {
                    isEditing = false
                } label: {
                    Text("Cancel")
                }
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    model = editingModel
                    isEditing = false
                } label: {
                    Text("Done")
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        
    }
}


//MARK: - Store
class ModelStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var models: [Model] = Model.mockModelArray()
    
    subscript(modelId: Model.ID?) -> Model {
        get {
            if let id = modelId {
                if let modelIndex = models.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id }) {
                    return models[modelIndex]
                }
            }
            
            if models.isEmpty {
                return Model(content: UUID().uuidString)
            } else {
                return models[0]
            }
        }
        
        set(newValue) {
            if let id = modelId {
                if let modelIndex = models.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id }) {
                    models[modelIndex] = newValue
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//MARK: - Models
struct Model: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var content: String
    static func mockModel() -> Model {
        Model(content: UUID().uuidString)
    }
    
    static func mockModelArray() -> [Model] {
        var array = [Model]()
        for _ in 0..<5 {
            array.append(mockModel())
        }
        return array
    }
}
```

Now upon confirmation the selected model is edited in all the views.